# How to configure UTM to remotely access SQL Server2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, utm

I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on my server and Configure SQL server and Windows firewall installed on server.It works fine over the LAN.
Now I am trying to access it over internet with the public ip of our server.We have installed UTM Fortigate firewall for security.
Can any one tell me how could I configure UTM for global access of SQL server ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure a VIP - Virtual IP, and a port mapping. The VIP needs to listen on your external interface, and re-direct the traffic to the internal server. Can be done in GUI, or via CLI:

```
config firewall vip
    edit "sql_server"
    set extintf "<external_if>"
    set portforward enable
    set mappedip <ip_of_server>
    set extport <external_port_number_to_listen_on>
    set mappedport <internal_port_on_server>
    end
end

config firewall policy
edit 0
    set srcintf "<external_if>"
    set dstintf "internal_if"
    set srcaddr "all"
    set dstaddr "sql_server"
    set action accept
    set schedule "always"
    set service "ALL"
end
end
```

However, by doing this you are exposing your sql server to the whole internet. I would strongly suggest you also use authentication and possibly limit the src IP scope allowed to access the VIP.